# Почему может не работать HmsInstanceId.deleteToken и HmsInstanceId.getToken?

Tags: android, push-уведомления, huawei

На некоторых устройствах `HmsInstanceId.deleteToken` выбрасывает исключение "com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 907135000: arguments invalid", а `HmsInstanceId.getToken` возвращает пустую строку?

У меня есть несколько устройств huawei без гугл сервисов, на которых эта проблема не воспроизводится (например JNY-LX1 ENUI 10.1.0). То есть на них я успешно получаю новый токен и принимаю уведомления.

А есть, например, устройство mediapad T5 EMUI 8.0.0 (и с гугл сервисами и с HMS Core одновременно), на котором пока никак не получилось заставить успешно отработать ни `HmsInstanceId.deleteToken` ни `HmsInstanceId.getToken`.
Пробовал ставить на телефоны разные версии HMS Core (сейчас тестирую на 6.6.0.311).
Судя по описанию моя проблема очень похожа на https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-push-clientdemo-android/issues/6, но коментарии оттуда мне никак не помогли.

Comment: Вопрос разобран на иностранном языке тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/72980715/4398606